# Styling HTML links within a flash file without using an external CSS file (AS2)?

Tags: html, css, flash, href, actionscript-2

I am having a nightmare using CSS to style HTML within a dynamic textfield in my flash doc. From what i now understand after much trial and error and reading online, CSS doesn't even work properly in flash even for the tags that it does understand (which are few and far between anyway). For some reason my layout is getting completely screwed up in certain scenarios (predominantly when there are images present too) when i hover over links (which are styled in an external CSS file). If i remove the external CSS styling (which only contains the following simple code):

```
a:link {text-decoration: none;}
a:active {text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Then everything works fine (but no links are underlined as standard or on hover). Does anyone know of any way to style the links without using an external CSS file (all i want to do is have no underline as standard and then underline them on hover). As this is from user input into a text editor I cannot place these links manually on the page in flash as they could be anywhere, I need a way of parsing the HTML and then displaying it accordingly.

Thanks so much for any help and advice anyone could offer as this has got me completely confused :)

Dave

Comment: I can't post this as answer since it's just too long ago that I'd to deal with this, but I think to remember that there was a `TextField.StyleSheet` class, which had a `setStyle()` method. You were possibly able to apply this stylesheet to the field via `my_textfield.styleSheet = my_stylesheet`. Maybe this gives you a hint what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var styles:TextField.StyleSheet = new TextField.StyleSheet();
styles.setStyle("html",{color:'#666666'});
styles.setStyle("a",{color:'#bf1f23'});

text.styleSheet = styles;
text.html = true;
```